# Advice for experienced developer trying Javascript for the first time

Tags: javascript

I'm very experienced in C/C++/Objective-C and over the last few days have been trying my hand at html/css/JS and am finding it very frustrating.

Time and time and time again I've been caught out as I've a syntax error or undeclared variable due to copying / pasting etc. with the consequence being that the code suddenly stops working then I have to scratch my head and figure out why.

The most painful thing is resorting to sprinkling alerts in the code everything something fails in order to track down the reason. I know there is the new console object for logging but it doesn't seem to work with Komodoedit or jsFiddle? Which is what I've been using.

Is there a way of using these tool, or alternative tools where I can step through the code line by line in a debugger like I can with other languages? Or any tricks for easy detection of problems with the code before executing it in addition to jslint?

[I don't want to use any libraries that might have built-in support for logging etc. as I'm finding they (well JQuery/JQuery mobile is) are drastically slowing down loading times on an iPhone so want to concentrate on pure JS.]

[My target browser is just iOS, but am using Komodoedit with Chrome most of the time and every few hours try it on an iPhone]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need several tools.

**First**, get yourself a real debugger.  I use the one built into Chrome.  There's a similar one built into Safari and Firebug available as an add-on for Firefox.  This will allow you to set breakpoints and step through your code and see exactly what is happening.

**Second**, get very used to running your code through [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/).  This will show you many obvious typos and encourage you to write robust code from day one.

**Third**, start writing in [`strict`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Strict_mode) mode.  This will again prevent some obvious typos and force you to start some good habits.

**Fourth**, use `console.log()` when needed.  Once you have a debugger, it's output will show in the debug console of the debugger for any page in your browser, including jsFiddle pages.  You will have to invoke the debugger on the right frame in jsFiddle and then it will work fine.  I use both a regular debugger and `console.log()` all the time with jsFiddle.  It takes a little figuring in jsFiddle and the debugger to find where your own code is to set breakpoints, but once you find it, it's easy to use.

**Fifth**, javascript is simply not C++.  While the syntax will seem quite familiar, the way you do things with anonymous functions and closures and objects and prototypes is very different.  As one who programmed in C++ for many, many years before learning javascript, I very much appreciate what I can do now in javascript that was a lot more work in C++, but it took awhile to get my brain into a new mode of thinking.  I spent too much time in my first years of javascript development trying to emulate C++ techniques rather than just learning the better way to accomplish the goal in javascript.

**Sixth**, you will have to change how you write and test code because of the lack of a compiler that finds errors for you.  I remember in the days of C++, when I needed to refactor something, I could make a bunch of changes and then let the compiler find all the other places I need to fix the syntax.  You can't do that with javascript.  When you make mass changes, you can run through jsLint to find some issues and then you literally need to execute every path to make sure everything works.  It is a bit of a pain.

**Seventh**, find a strategy/tools for unit testing.  Once a project gets more than a few functions long, you will benefit greatly from building unit tests that you can run anytime you make significant changes.  They will both find issues for you in a lot less time than without the unit tests and they will give you the courage to refactor and clean up your code when you see the need for that because you know the unit tests will tell you if everything is working again.  It's extra work up front that pays dividends many times over down the road.

Comment: Also, use unit testing - I like Jasmine, but there are many other options.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has an add-on called FireBug that is very helpful for debugging CSS/javascript, and yes, it does have the ability to step through a script as well as a command line where you can try out various javascript expressions.  I'm pretty sure Chrome has a similar feature.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article in which you get a list of tools to debug the javascript
[advance-javascript-debugging-techniques](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/04/03/advanced-javascript-debugging-techniques/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Chrome, you just need to open the developer console (spanner -> tools -> javascript console, or Ctrl+Alt+J (at a guess)). Instead of sprinkling your code with alerts, use `console.log`, `console.error`, and `console.info` to print to it. All of those are variadic, so you can pass as much to one call as you need.

In addition to this, you can use the console to test and modify parts of your code on the fly,  or to just try out a few snippets to see if they work. It's a fully functional REPL that also works with the current document.

In the **sources** tab of the developer console, you are able to set breakpoints and step through your code, analysing state at each point. This page goes into some detail about it: http://chromedevtools.googlecode.com/svn-history/r421/trunk/tutorials/breapoints/index.html

In the **elements** tab, you are able to set breakpoints on changes to elements in the DOM, including changes to attributes and child nodes. Right click a node and select the option you want. This will come in handy when debugging code that is asynchronous and plays with the document (eg. AJAX calls inserting new content).

In addition to this, you can scroll to the bottom of the styles pane to the right, and open the **event listeners** section. Here, you can inspect all the events bound to the selected DOM node.

You can enter `debugger` (without a semicolon) into your code, and it will open the sources tab at that point so you can inspect the code further. I think this may be Chrome specific.

Finally, tools like JSlint will help you spot undeclared variables as you code, as well as cases where the formatting of your code creates unexpected errors, and some might even go as far as using syntax highlighting to make you notice variables that are undefined.

This is also just scraping the surface. Your editor and JSlint can make your code *look* right and parse without error, but the browser and its console is where you will spend most of your time.